# When we should not call parseint in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why making:

```
var x = prompt(“give a value”)
x = parseInt(x) 
var y = x*2
```

Is similar to do

```
var x = prompt(“give a value”)
var y = x*2
```

So why we can do the multiplication without making the conversion.

Comment: Search for `js type coercion`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only with +. In such a case we will get concatenation